# React-Native Error: failed to get balance of account 3pdz6cSKYuDUbGULydExPfihakTJP7p5VCgoerathkr6: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined value to object

Tags: solana-program, web3.js

i am using this in react native and amazed with thing that in one project its giving me the balance without any error but that project is only for testing ,but when i integrated it with the main project it gives me the above mentioned error i also doubled checked the versions for both but still getting this, attaching my code snippest below

```
  const connection = new Web3.Connection('https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com');

  // 5YNmS1R9nNSCDzb5a7mMJ1dwK9uHeAAF4CmPEwKgVWr8
  const feePayer = Web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(
    base58.decode(
      'reQRFKEf8jk9BZ8AptA2xww3qQ4h8omtvheKBaG9u2cBGjRcj547wVgQDkQgbPrsu2Z6phTonpAocaqmxGTR7ox',
    ),
  );
  const getBalanceSol = async () => {
    try {
      let balance = await connection.getBalance(feePayer.publicKey);
      console.log(`${balance / Web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL} SOL`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error while getting balance ', error);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there's an error in your secret key. When I try to run this locally, I get:

```
.../node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:9870
      throw new Error('bad secret key size');
            ^

Error: bad secret key size
    at Keypair.fromSecretKey (.../node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:9870:13)
    at .../index.js:4:26
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
```

So be sure that the base58 version of your private key is correct!

Comment: Jon C thanks for your attention but in my case private key was ok ,that what i got after retry i posted in my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Actually i was using @ethersproject/shims this package caused that error after just removing import of this package it worked for me